# How can I make Eclipse's JDT objects Serializable?

Tags: java, eclipse, serialization, aspectj, eclipse-jdt

I am creating an eclipse plugin: a refactoring tool that uses Eclipse's JDT libraries. Part of the project is to utilize another library, a process-programming language that requires objects be Serializable in order to be passed between steps. I wish I could change this but I cannot, so I need a way to make an AST object Serializable.

My first attempt was to define a proxy class that implements Serializable and holds a transient AST, and use libraries such as XStream and GSON to actually serialize and deserialize the AST. However I was running into circular reference errors there. I still like this idea but I haven't found a library capable of doing it.

Any other ideas? Will altering the source and recompiling affect the portability of the plugin? Would this be possible with load-time aspect weaving?

Answer (score 0):

I think downloading the source, adding serializable, and repackaging would be the correct course of action here. I ended up switching to a different library, [javaparser](https://code.google.com/p/javaparser/), which has a simpler codebase and is easier to alter.